# Custom parent view entirely redrawn when part of custom child view is invalidated?

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

I have just started making custom views in Android, so I am yet to learn all the facts about the paint (draw) cycles for view hierarchies, and the effective use of View methods `invalidate` and `onDraw`.  But I have come across a puzzling behaviour.

I have a custom viewgroup, extending the **RelativeLayout** class. That is my parent view.  Within that, as children, I have several custom child views.  From time to time, in response to user actions, I need to redraw various parts of these views, both parent and childen.

Typically this is the sequence of events. From within a child view class I invalidate a small area of it, by calling `invalidate(rct)` where rct is the Rect that delimits the area I need to update.

The puzzling thing is that this very localised action provokes a truly excessive and global response. It seems - from the evidence of my LogCat trace output - that:

(1) the *entire* parent view undergoes a complete redraw

followed by:

(2) every child view undergoes a complete redraw

Admittedly, if response (1) happens then (2) should indeed follow, as all child views would then need complete repainting.  But why does (1) happen at all?

Is that the normal behaviour for the paint cycle of a view hierarchy?  If so, it seems so *wrong!*  I would have expected, instead, that only a small area of the parent might need to be redrawn, directly underlying the rectangle marked dirty in the child view that is to be redrawn.  And, further, even that small area of the parent should need redrawing only if the overlying child is not fully opaque in that area.

The evidence for this seemingly *nuke-the-lot* wholesale redrawing activity is that in each onDraw method body for each of my custom views, I have a LogCat trace statement as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
   Rect rct = new Rect();     
   Boolean doDraw = c.getClipBounds(rct);
   Log.v(LOGTAG, "onDraw Entry doDraw=" + doDraw + "  rct=" + rct);

   ....  
}
```

The LogCat output makes it clear that each onDraw call is for the *entire* surface of the view.

Comment: I think all onDraws() will always be called. The thing is, the underlying graphics engine discards paint operations outside the clipping region. But I'm still learning about this :)